# Deduce all characters behind decimal number, with leading 0's

Tags: c#, string, output

If I have an input string, *input* has Three or more decimals I want the string to be handled by a separate `if-loop`.

I've created the following console program for this purpose, where the `if-loop` is entered if (the first constraint) there is a decimal point, `.` in the string and (the second constraint) if the amount of decimals are Three or more.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "0.065";
            string output;

            Console.WriteLine(input.ToString());  // (1)
            Console.WriteLine(input.ToString().IndexOf("."));  // (2)
            Console.WriteLine(input.ToString().Substring(input.ToString().IndexOf("."))); // (3)

            if (Convert.ToInt32(input.IndexOf('.')) != -1 && 
            Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1).Length) >= 3)
            {
                output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(output));
            }
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the expected result, i.e.

(1) prints `0.065`,

(2) prints `1`,

(3) prints `.065`

and (4) prints `3`.

My issue is that when I remove the hard coded string value, `input = "0.065"` and replace it with

```
input = Row["Price"].ToString();
```

where `Row["Price"].ToString();` is a value from a XML file, which also has value `0.065` I get the following prints from console:

(1) yields `0.065`

(2) yields `-1` (should be 1 as there is a `.` present)

(3) yields `0.065` (should be `.065`)

and (4) is not printed, because the `if constraints` are not met.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I am new to C#, but I figure that since `input` is of type `string` in both cases, there shouldn't be any difference? Especially as I apply `ToString()` to my new `string input`?

Comment: `Row["Price"].ToString(); is a value from a XML file` certainly doesn't look like something read from an XML. Could you please include the code where you are reading that value and what `Row` is?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no , instead of a . in that string then you `input = Row["Price"].ToString();`

Comment: Well that just means your input doesn't contain "." character, even if you think it does. Maybe it contains comma instead of dot, or something else - we cannot figure it out. Just do `Console.WriteLine(Row["Price"].ToString())` and see yourself.

Comment: May be your Row["Price"] contains a numeric value with "," as a separator and not "."

Comment: @k.Lennartz   I've printed `input` and I didn't see a `,` but a `.`. But when I did `input = Row["Price"].ToString().Replace(",",".")` then it worked so it must have been because they look so very similar (my real print uses a function which prints with bold so the difference between `,` and `.` is even more subtle. Three people suggested this, but since you were first I believe it's right that if you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `,` with an `.` in that string when you do `input = Row["Price"].ToString();`.

Replace function is `input = Row["Price"].ToString().Replace(",", ".");`